# 1117 Regulator outputting 4.2v

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp8266

I have an esp-12 soldered on [this](https://www.upgradeindustries.com/product/138/ESP-12-ESP-07-Breadboard-Adapter) breadboard adapter. I mounted a 1117 3.3V (not adjustable ones) regulator to the board and removed the 0 Ohm jumper resistor as instructed by the manufacturer.
Using a regulated 5V power supply, I powered it up but I noticed it is getting hot. I measured the voltage on esp-12 power pins and it reads about 4.2V. I changed the regulator multiple times but the result was the same.
Any Ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the footprint is not pin compatible with LM1117.
the pin order for the regulator on the PCB from left to right is : GND-IN-OUT.